# Python string concatenation not working as expected

Tags: python, string-concatenation

```
out = 'Hello'
print( out.join([' world']) )
```

When I run it, it shows

```
world
```

Isn't it supposed to print hello world?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it joins the elements of the list with the word `'Hello'`. For example, if you had `['A', 'B']`, it would produce `'AHelloB'`. Since there is only one element in your list, there is nothing to join, so it can just return the only element in there unchanged.

What you wanted is probably something like `' '.join(['Hello', 'world'])`.

Answer (score 2):

`join()` behaves slightly differently to how you expect. It takes a list of words to join. The seed word is what you put between the joins.

```
' '.join(['Hello', 'world'])
>> Hello world

','.join(['Hello', 'world'])
>> Hello,world

'/'.join(['name', 'location', 'age'])
>> name/location/age

'*'.join(['name'])
>> name

'hello'.join(['world'])
>> world
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your array contains only one entry `" world"` there is nothing to join.